# Chef - looking for a better way to find the last octet of an IP address.

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I'd like to know what would be the best way to populate a Chef attribute in a cookbook with the last octet of the IP address.

Here is how I do it now. It seems to work; however,I'd like to know how I can improve it.

```
default['application']['host_ip'] = node['network']['interfaces']['eth0']['addresses'].keys[1]
default['application']['app_id'] = node['application']['host_ip'].split('.')[-1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks fine. You might want some error handling since this will crash if there isn't an `eth0`, but that's up to you. You could also use `node['ipaddress']` which is the IP on the default interface.